# Trouble understanding proof of monotonic discontinuity theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am new to real analysis and I have trouble understanding Rudin's and other similar proofs of this:-

**Theorem**: Let $f$ be monotonic on $(a,b)$. Then the set of points of $(a,b)$ at which $f$ is discontinuous is at most countable.

**Proof**: Suppose, for the sake of definiteness, that $f$ is increasing, and
let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous.
With every point $x$ of $E$ we associate a rational number $r(x)$ such
that
$f(x-) < r(x) <f(x+)$.
Since $x_1 < x_2$ implies $f(x_1 +) ≤ f(x_2 - )$, we see that $r(x_1) ≠ r(x_2 )$ if
$x_1 ≠ x_2$.
We have thus established a 1-1 correspondence between the set E and
a subset of the set of rational numbers. The latter, as we know, is countable.

So the issue I'm having is that, it seems the whole proof is pinned on the rational numbers and its cardinality. I'm thinking why rational numbers, can't $r(x)$ be real numbers also, in which case wouldn't it become uncountable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not. The real numbers have both countable and uncountable subsets; establishing a $1$-$1$ correspondence between the discontinuities and a subset of $\Bbb R$ would leave open the possibility that the subset in question (and hence the set of discontinuities) is **un**countable. It would show only that there are no more discontinuities than there are real numbers, which is obvious anyway. Establishing a $1$-$1$ correspondence between the discontinuities and a subset of the rational numbers, on the other hand, guarantees that there are only countably many discontinuities, because **every** subset of the rationals is countable.

Comment: I have some follow up questions 1. How can a bijection exists between x and rationals Q when there is a jump discontinuity at x. Doesn't it become a one to many function at said point? 2. If we are just mapping from set E to Q, then what happens to the points between f(x-) and f(x+) which are irrational? they don't seem to get "counted". I know I must be wrong but it feels like we are cheating by using rationals here.

Comment: @Sark: We’re not interested in counting those points: we’re trying to count the discontinuities, so we pick one point in each of the gaps (jump discontinuities). We’re picking rational points, so we can only pick countably many of them, and since we pick one point per gap, there can only be countably many gaps.

Comment: Omg, I totally misunderstood the proof. So x1, x2,..... are the points where the different discontinuities exists. Say I look at it from a different perspective, since x1 and x2 are on the real line, we can have a discontinuity exists at any point between x1 and x2 rational or irrational, in this case doesn't it become uncountably many?

Comment: @Sark: The point of the theorem is that it can happen at only countably many different points $x_n$. Each discontinuity involves a gap on the $y$-axis that contains no values of the function, and because $f$ is monotone, those gaps cannot overlap. In each of them we pick a rational number, and because the gaps don’t overlap, those rationals are all different. Thus, there can be only countably many gaps, no matter where they occur.

Comment: yes yes. I see it now, the jump discontinuities can't overlap and must keep increasing since its monotonic. So you can't just keep adding discontinuities as you please i.e 0.000....001 at the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you very much. Studying analysis alone can feel pretty hopeless sometimes.

Comment: @Sark: You’re very welcome. No, it’s definitely not the easiest subject to pick up on one’s own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work, but the conclusion would then be that the cardinal of the set of the points at which $f$ is discontinuous is *at most* the same as the cardinal of $\Bbb R$, which is something that we already know.